# Re-select and upload the same file

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

You cannot re-select and upload the same file except in Firefox, which mistakenly allows you to do so:

```
<input type="file" id="fileChooser">
document.getElementById('fileChooser').onchange = function () {
    alert('Uploaded!');
};
```

Here's my approach to resolve the issue. I wonder if there's a neater way to achieve it.

```
<input type="file" id="fileChooser">
var fileChooser = document.getElementById('fileChooser');
fileChooser.onclick = function () {
    this.value = '';
};
fileChooser.onchange = function () {
    if (this.value) {
        alert('Uploaded!');
    }
};
```

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scMF6/2/

**Explanation:**

You cannot re-select the same file twice in a row, i.e. you select and upload `foo.txt` on your desktop, for example, and then click the file chooser again, file select dialog appears and you try to select the same file again -- the browser simply does nothing and no alert box appears.

Comment: Mind explaining the issue you're trying to solve better? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'd like to select and upload the same file, but I can't, as it doesn't trigger a `change` event.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting a change event on Chrome and IE as well. AFAIK file inputs' `.onchange` works pretty much on any browser.

Comment: I need to explain more: you cannot reselect/reupload the same file, i.e. if you choose a file, you cannot choose it again -- it simply does nothing.

Comment: Ohh I see. You want to trigger an event when the user re-selects the same file then, it is good info to add to the question. I fear that it may not be easily achievable though.

Comment: Maybe it's my poor English, but doesn't upload the _same file_ have the meaning we're talking about?

Comment: In my opinion, "Upload the same file" implies that you're submitting/sending the same file twice. In your case, you're selecting it before submission.

Comment: @Hermes "Same file" didn't mean much to me until you explained that, in this scenario, you already selected a file with a fileChooser.

Comment: I think your solution is a pretty good one! It may not be pretty, but such is the way of the webpage.

Comment: Might be, convert the image to base64 & save it in a variable and `onchange event` compare the new image with the variable...

Comment: @Bhavik: When you cannot re-select a file, how can you access its content and compare it with the content of the file which is already selected? Maybe I don't understand your solution. Then please show it throw a fiddle/some snippet. Thanks!

Comment: Just updated my demo so it works well in IE11.

Comment: What is "same file" meaning/context/scope here? Several file fields on a single form should not point to the same user filesystem file? Diferent file fields in defferent forms along some kind of user "session"? In that case, if the content of the file changes keeping the same name (in the user enviroment) should it be considered "same file"? I'd like to know some more background information about the case you are thinking about.

Comment: @miguel-svq: I mean you cannot re-select the same file twice in a row, i.e. you select and upload `foo.txt` on your desktop, for example, and then click the file chooser again, file select dialog appears and you try to select the same file again -- the browser simply does nothing and no alert box appears.

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: I think i get ur question but what are you trying to achieve with this??? You can clear field after submit...

Comment: @AD7six: Is it a bad idea to ask if there's a better way to do something or any improvement to the current approach?

Comment: @hermes - where do you ask that? But yes - this isn't codereview, asking for opinions is off topic. See the faq/help for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for idea!
If some one use GWT, then you can use this code)

```
     ...//some code :)
     Event.setEventListener(btn, new EventListener() {    
           @Override
           public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
           //work with IE11+ and other modern browsers
           nativeClearFile(fileUpload.getElement());
           //throw event click 
           InputElement.as(fileUpload.getElement()).click();
           }
          });
    Event.sinkEvents(btn, Event.ONCLICK);
    ...//continue code :)

    private native void nativeClearFile(Element element) /*-{
        element.value = '';
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has one problem, after selecting a file when you click it second time it clears the file input. Now if user does not select a new file and cancels Browse pop up then his old selection is gone.

This is not the default behavior of file input in FF.

I guess if you have some handle or callback for upload then you should clear your file input in that.

Comment: "_This is not the default behavior of file input in FF._" But it is the default behavior in Chrome & Opera. "_I guess if you have some handle or callback for upload then you should clear your file input in that._" I wonder how I can do that. Would you mind providing an example/snippet?

Comment: @Sanjeev OP wanted to know if there is a neater problem to solve. You mentioned the problem in his approach but not the solution. Please use comments for this as I would not consider as an answer

Comment: @Hermes : You have not mentioned how you are submitting or uploading file, is it a multipart form submit(enctype="multipart/form-data")?

Comment: @blunderboy: i agree i should not have put this as answer, my bad.

Comment: Suppose it's a simple file read process like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/tJBHZ/).

Comment: Then you can set document.getElementById('fileChooser').value=""; in reader.onload after setting this.result.

Comment: IMHO my approach is much better: you're simply removing the usability of file name displayed on the page.

Comment: @Hermes: In the context of above demo i think your approach is fine.May be you can also show the file name above the file content area , this will avoid confusion for user in case the file input gets cleared.

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize "change event"  after "click event":

```
 var fileChooser = document.getElementById('fileChooser');
    fileChooser.onclick = function () {
        this.value = '';
        fileChooser.onchange = function () {
            if (this.value) {
                alert('Uploaded!');
            }
        };
    };
```

Comment: Etiquette on stackoverflow is to explain code only answers.

Comment: My English is bad. I am sorry :(